# Multi dimensional Indexing with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

I'm using a 3 dimensional array, that is defined like this:

```
x = np.zeros((dim1, dim2, dim3), dtype=np.float32)
```

After inserting some data I need to apply a function only if values in specific columns are still zero.
The columns I'm interested in are selected by this array containing the correct indexes

```
scale_idx = np.array([0,1,3])
```

therefore what I'm trying to do is to use indexing to select those row and columns.

At first i tried to do this, using a boolean mask for the first 2 dimensions, using an array for the third:

```
x[x[:,:,scale_idx].any(axis =2)] ,scale_idx]
```

but I get this error:

```
IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,) (2,) (3,)
```

If I change the last index to `:` I get all the row I'm interested in,  but i get all the possible columns, I was expecting that the last array would act as an indexer, as explained in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html.

```
x[x[:,:,scale_idx].any(axis =2)]
```

My `scale_idx` should be interpreted as a column indexers but are actually interpreted as row indexes, therefore, since only 2 rows respect the condition but i have 3 indexes, I get an `IndexError`.

I have found a workaround to this using

```
x[x[:,:,scale_idx].any(axis =2)][:,:,scale_idx]
```

but it's kinda ugly and, since it's a slice, i can't modify the original array.

Anybody willing to explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT:
Thanks to @hpaulj I've managed to isolate the cells I need, after that I've created a matrix with the same shape of the selected values, and assigned the values to the masked cells, to my surprise, the new values are not the ones I just set but are some random integers that I can't figure out where they came from.
Code to reproduce:

```
scale_idx = np.array([0,3,1])
b = x[:,:,scale_idx].any(axis =2)
I, J = np.nonzero(b)
x[I[:,None], J[:,None], scale_idx] #this selects the correct cells
>>>
array([[ 50,  50,  50],
     [100, 100, 100],
     [100, 100, 100]])
scaler.transform(x[I[:,None], J[:,None], scale_idx]) #sklearn standard scaler, returns a matrix with the scaled values
>>>
array([[-0.50600345, -0.5445559 , -1.2957878 ],
     [-0.50600345, -0.25915199, -1.22266904],
     [-0.50600345, -0.25915199, -1.22266904]]) 
x[I[:,None], J[:,None], scale_idx] = scaler.transform(x[I[:,None], J[:,None], scale_idx]) #assign the new values to the selected cells
x[I[:,None], J[:,None], scale_idx] #check the new values

array([[0, 2, 0],
     [0, 6, 2],
     [0, 6, 2]])
```

Why are the new values different from what I'm expecting?

Comment: Can you share a dummy example with specific dimensions? Hard to tell what to make out of the 20

Comment: I'm sorry, that 20 should not have appeared, I've refactored the code a bit, it should be clearer now, I still can't figure out why it's not working. Maybe boolean mask plus array indexer is not supported?

Comment: Another indexing reference: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: you can't set the values of an `int` to floats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's take the 3d boolean mask example from the `indexing` docs:

```
In [135]: x = np.arange(30).reshape(2,3,5) 
     ...: b = np.array([[True, True, False], [False, True, True]])                             
In [136]: x                                                                                    
Out[136]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
        [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
        [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]]])
In [137]: b                                                                                    
Out[137]: 
array([[ True,  True, False],
       [False,  True,  True]])
In [138]: x[b]                                                                                 
Out[138]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

This is a 2d array.  The mask `b` selects elements from the first 2 dimensions.  The `False` values cause it to skip the [10...] and [15...] rows.

We can slice on the last dimension:

```
In [139]: x[b,:3]                                                                              
Out[139]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 5,  6,  7],
       [20, 21, 22],
       [25, 26, 27]])
```

but a list index will produce an error (unless it's length 4):

```
In [140]: x[b,[0,1,2]]                                                                         
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-140-7f1dbec100f2> in <module>
----> 1 x[b,[0,1,2]]

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (4,) (3,)
```

The reason is that the boolean mask effectively translates into index with the `np.where` arrays:

```
In [141]: np.nonzero(b)                                                                        
Out[141]: (array([0, 0, 1, 1]), array([0, 1, 1, 2]))
```

`nonzero` found 4 nonzero elements.  The `x[b]` indexing is then:

```
In [143]: x[[0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,2],:]                                                             
Out[143]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
```

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing

The shape mismatch then becomes more obvious:

```
In [144]: x[[0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,2],[1,2,3]]                                                       
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-144-1efd76049cb0> in <module>
----> 1 x[[0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,2],[1,2,3]]

IndexError: shape mismatch: indexing arrays could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (4,) (3,)
```

If the lists match in size, the indexing runs, but produces a 'diagonal', not a block:

```
In [145]: x[[0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,2],[1,2,3,4]]                                                     
Out[145]: array([ 1,  7, 23, 29])
```

As you found the two stage indexing works - but not for setting values

```
In [146]: x[[0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,2]][:,[1,2,3]]                                                    
Out[146]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [26, 27, 28]])
```

We can get the block by 'transposing' the last index list:

```
In [147]: x[[0,0,1,1],[0,1,1,2],[[1],[2],[3]]]                                                 
Out[147]: 
array([[ 1,  6, 21, 26],
       [ 2,  7, 22, 27],
       [ 3,  8, 23, 28]])
```

Ok, this is the transpose.  We could apply transpose to it.  Or we could transpose the `b` arrays first:

```
In [148]: I,J=np.nonzero(b)                                                                    
In [149]: x[I[:,None], J[:,None], [1,2,3]]                                                     
Out[149]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [26, 27, 28]])
```

And this works for setting

```
In [150]: x[I[:,None], J[:,None], [1,2,3]]=0                                                   
In [151]: x                                                                                    
Out[151]: 
array([[[ 0,  0,  0,  0,  4],
        [ 5,  0,  0,  0,  9],
        [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]],

       [[15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20,  0,  0,  0, 24],
        [25,  0,  0,  0, 29]]])
```

It's a long answer.  I had a general idea of what was happening, but needed to work out the details.  Plus, you need to understand what's going on.

Comment: thanks a lot for the extensive answer, I've managed to use boolean indexing using the transposition trick and it worked. But I still cant set the new values correctly, I've updated my question with the new info.